# Show that $S_n/n$ converges almost surely to 0 if $X_n$ converges to 0 a.s

Tags: probability, self-study, convergence

Suppose we have a sequence of random variables ${X_n}$,
$$X_n\xrightarrow{a.s.}0$$
Prove this implies
$$\frac{S_n}{n}\xrightarrow{a.s.}0$$
where $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k$.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are the $X_i$ independent?

Comment: It doesn't say anything about the independence in the question.

Comment: I know that but many times the OPs neglect some assumption(s) in their post.  So I wanted it clarified because it could affect a proof given in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

$X_n \to^{a.s.} 0$ implies $\exists N$ such that $\forall \omega \in N^{c}$, $X_n(\omega)\to 0$ with $P(N)=0$. Fix $\omega_0 \in N^{c}$ for that $\omega_0$, $X_n(\omega_0)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.  So by Cesaro Means Theorem we get that $\frac{S_n (\omega_0)}{n}\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. So $S_n/n \to 0$ $\forall \omega \in N^{c}$ with $P(N)=0$. Therefore $\frac{S_n}{n}\to 0$ almost surely.